# parameter passing to a standalone qooxdoo application

Tags: parameter-passing, qooxdoo

How can I pass parameters to a stand alone qooxdoo applicatoin?

Thanks in advance :)

**update:**

I was thinking of passing URL parameters; something like GET/POST params when an html FORM is submitted. Initially, "arguments" in standalone application caught my attention. I think Tobi has correctly answered me (thanks a bunch); but feel free to share your ideas!

Comment: It depends on what kind of parameter you think of and where the parameter come from? Do you think of URL parameter?

Comment: You can have build time or runtime settings. Build time settings are defined as part of the build process, while runtime settings can e.g. be passed as URL parameters or in cookies. The answer depends on what exactly you try to achieve. Maybe you can give us a little use case.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `qx.bom.History` it allows you to access the part of the url after the # sign. With this you can allow remote control of your application via urls of the form

```
http://host/app#param1=x;param2=y
```

Coupled with running the qooxdoo app in a named window (html target) this works pretty well.

cheers
tobi